# Adding CSS and JS to <head> using a module layout.xml for block

Tags: module, layout, magento-1.8, css, javascript

## Synopsis

I would like to add a block to my grouped product view and my simple product view.  This block will have some nice tooltips for hover states, i'm using a small library with one jquery plugin and one css stylesheet.

I wish to include these two resources in the  of magento on only these pages.

## Notes

- I am running a custom theme;
- Caching is *disabled*; and
- My files are inside the `/js` directory;

## Thus far…

Nevertheless I knew one way was to use `layout.xml` in my module, at first this didn't work so I thought maybe I needed additional configuration inside my `config.xml` to tell Magento about my layout requirements - this too didn't work.

By *didn't work* what I mean is, my assets weren't loaded.

*Please find the attached source below.*

---

***app/code/local/Vendor/Rating/etc/layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

***app/code/local/Vendor/Rating/etc/config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    ...

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <vendor_rating>
                    <file>layout.xml</file>
                </vendor_rating>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    ...

</config>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, your layout file should be placed in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/`.
Second. If you want to add the css and js files only in the grouped and simple product pages don't use the `<default>` layout handle.
Make your layout look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <my_handle><!-- declare a custom handle so you won't duplicate the code -->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </my_handle>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple><!-- layout handle for simple products -->
        <update handle="my_handle" /> <!-- include the handle you declared above -->
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped><!-- layout handle for grouped products -->
        <update handle="my_handle" /> <!-- include the handle you declared above -->
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense.  I presume since my `config.xml` defines the name of the layout xml file I can call this anything I wanted?

Comment: @Takingsides. Yes. The name can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

As this has not been pointed out clearly enough yet:

#### Directories

Layout XML files for a custom module should be theme independent and thus placed into

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout
```

You can override any of these XML files in your custom theme, but in most cases, it is better to have an additional theme specific layout file that *adds* changes. More info: 
[What is the correct way/approach to modify a Magento template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72903/243)

#### File names

Note that those files are sometimes referred to as "layout.xml files", but `layout.xml` is actually not a file name you would usually find in any Magento code. Your code works if you put your `layout.xml` file in the right location (see above), but convention is to use the lower case module name:

```
rating.xml
```

or better

```
vendor_rating.xml
```

Remember that the layout XML files from all modules are in one single directory, so the name must be unique!

Answer (score 1):

Your layout.xml should go inside

> app/design/frontend/[YOUR CUSTOM PACKAGE]/[YOUR CUSTOM THEME]/layout/

Answer (score 0):

As stated above for your particular case you should not use it inside `<default>` tags but for example purposes you can add css files that reside in your root magento /js directory by this way in your `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/layout/local.xml` for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
             <action method="addItem">
                <type>js_css</type>
                <stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet>
                <params>media="all"</params>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```