# Modify Magento Carousel - itemslider

Tags: design, js-css

On my Homepage, I have a Carousel with products and Featured Products that are displaying the slider with arrows on each side. But of course, I see all breaks in IE8. Every image of a product on the carousel is displaying on a single row like there's a "display: block;" property applied. So I found styles.css in two folders, of my Interface folder but when I modify the Carousel Styles -> nothing is happening at all. I saw there are dynamically created CSS files but I'm not really familiar with that technique. So I just want to apply a different CSS file for that item slider to clean the IE8 mess. I registered my CSS file with a condition in the local.XML file. But again -> nothing happens.

Here's the store: http://dev.elmaira.bg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it looks like you have Magento merging your CSS into one dynamically generated file. You can turn this off in **Admin > System > Configuration > Developer > CSS Settings >  Merge CSS Files**. You can test by turning that setting off.

However, this is a generally good, though imperfect, feature to have turned on in production. When you confirm that your CSS changes work with the merge off, you can turn the merge back on and clear the current generated files in **Admin > System > Cache Management > Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache**. You may also need to flush your browser's cache as well as Magento tends to regenerate the same hash for the file name unless additional files are added.

Comment: Thanks for thoose tips! It may help someone else but it's not working for me. My CSS isn't merged, I flushed the CSS/JS cache, not using browser cache at all. So... I've tried to edit the auto generated css file in 'public_html/cssmedia/' and it worked but It seems to me so superficial to edit a file with that name 'd14cee8ab70814ea50994dd700b9dabe.css', is there a way to add my custom css file to fix IE8 bugs in this case?
If you have any suggestions, I'll be glad to read them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer here should be instructive to add your own css to Magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11860/adding-css-and-js-to-head-using-a-module-layout-xml-for-block

Comment: I know this. But it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway.